# Adaptive gridlines

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I want to use gridlines to create an effect of [millimeter graphing paper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_paper) on a 2d graph, to show how multi-variable function depends on 1 variable. The scales of different variables differ a lot, so my naive approach (that I have used before) does not seem to work.

Example of what I have at the moment:

```
<< ErrorBarPlots`
Cmb[x_, y_, ex_, ey_] := {{N[x], N[y]}, ErrorBar[ex, ey]};
SetAttributes[Cmb, Listable];

ELP[x_, y_, ex_, ey_, name_] :=
 ErrorListPlot[
  Cmb[x, y, ex, ey],
  PlotRange -> FromTo[x, y],
  PlotLabel -> name,
  Joined -> True, Frame -> True, GridLines -> GetGrid,
  ImageSize -> {600}
 ]
```

Both `FromTo` (I want to leave 5% margin in the frame) and `GetGrid` do not work exactly as I want them to.

On some axes the variables differs many orders of 10. And I do not want, that one axis has many orders of 10 gridlines more then other. And most importantly I want the gridlines to line up with ticks.

Sample data:

```
ELP[
  {4124961/25000000, 27573001/100000000, 9162729/25000000, 44635761/
   100000000, 15737089/25000000, 829921/1562500, 4405801/4000000, 
   23068809/25000000, 329386201/100000000, 58079641/100000000},
  {1/10, 1/5, 3/10, 2/5, 3/5, 1/2, 1/2, 1/2, 1/2, 1/2},
  {2031/(250000 Sqrt[10]), 5251/(500000 Sqrt[10]), 3027/(
   250000 Sqrt[10]), 6681/(500000 Sqrt[10]), 3967/(250000 Sqrt[10]), 
   911/(62500 Sqrt[10]), 2099/(100000 Sqrt[10]), 4803/(
   250000 Sqrt[10]), 18149/(500000 Sqrt[10]), 7621/(500000 Sqrt[10])},
  {1/2000, 1/1000, 3/2000, 1/500, 3/1000, 1/400, 1/400, 1/400, 1/400, 
   1/400},
  "T2, m"
]
```

Would result in:

[image]

And my naive GetGrid, that works in some sence:

```
FromTo[x_, y_] := Module[{dx, dy},
   dx = (Max[x] - Min[x])*0.1;
   dy = (Max[y] - Min[y])*0.1;
   {{Min[x] - dx, Max[x] + dx}, {Min[y] - dy, Max[y] + dy}}];
GetGrid[min_, max_] := Module[{step, i},
  step = (max - min)/100;
  Table[
   {min + i*step,
    If[Equal[Mod[i, 10], 0],
     Directive[Gray, Thick, Opacity[0.5]],
     If[Equal[Mod[i, 5], 0],
      Directive[Gray, Opacity[0.5]],
      Directive[LightGray, Opacity[0.5]]
      ]]},
   {i, 1, 100}]
  ]
```

### Question

How to make GridLines line up with ticks?

edit: With

```
GetTicks[x_, y_] := Module[{dx, dy},
   dx = (Max[x] - Min[x])*0.1;
   dy = (Max[y] - Min[y])*0.1;
   {
    Min[x] - dx + Table[i*dx*1.2, {i, 1, 9}],
    Min[y] - dy + Table[i*dy*1.2, {i, 1, 9}]
    }];

ELP[x_, y_, ex_, ey_, name_] :=
 ErrorListPlot[
  Cmb[x, y, ex, ey],
  PlotRange -> FromTo[x, y],
  PlotLabel -> name,
  Joined -> True, Frame -> True, GridLines -> GetGrid, 
  FrameTicks -> GetTicks[x, y],
  ImageSize -> {600},
  AspectRatio -> 1
  ]
```

I can get:

[image]

And that is a lot better. But I would like to shift the grid and not the ticks.

edit: @Sjoerd C. de Vries

Your solution does what I wanted to archive and works. I also noticed, that if I take first 5 elements of sample data, then the plot will be (elements are sorted and regression line is added).
[image]

Notice the left most element is like off grid.

Comment: You may want to insert Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"] for completeness. Do you intend the gridlines to form a square raster? In that case you have to play with `AspectRatio` as well.

Comment: @Sjoerd C. de Vries : Yes, your right.

Comment: If you want to specify the locations of your tick marks, I'd suggest using [LevelScheme](http://wnsl.physics.yale.edu/levelscheme/). It's `CustomTicks` package is far superior to the built-in capabilities, and you don't you have to write your own code, which is error prone, to set up custom specifications.

Comment: @rcollyer : Interesting resource.

Comment: Apparently, custom grid lines is supposed to be in the next version of LevelScheme. I don't know if it will be capable of three levels of styles, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't use FrameTicks but shift the grid correctly. This is a first approach. Dinner waits.

```
getGrid[min_, max_] :=
 Module[{step, i},
  Print[{min, max}];
  step = 1/100;
  Table[
   {
    Floor[min, 0.1] + i*step,
    If[Equal[Mod[i, 10], 0], Directive[Gray, Thick, Opacity[0.5]],
     If[Equal[Mod[i, 5], 0], Directive[Gray, Opacity[0.5]],
      Directive[LightGray, Opacity[0.5]]
      ]
     ]
    },
   {i, 1, (Ceiling[max, 0.1] - Floor[min, 0.1])/step // Round}
   ]
  ]
```

Use an AspectRatio that's appropriate for the grid (probably the ratio of x and y ranges)

---

**After-dinner update**

To make it more robust for different value ranges (per your comment) I generate the ticks that would be chosen by `ListPlot` and base my steps on that:

```
getGrid[min_, max_] :=
 Module[{step, i,j},
  i = Cases[(Ticks /. 
       AbsoluteOptions[ListPlot[{{min, min}, {max, max}}], 
        Ticks])[[1]], {a_, ___, {_, AbsoluteThickness[0.25`]}} :> a];
  step = i[[2]] - i[[1]];
  Table[
   {
    i[[1]] + j*step/10,
    If[Equal[Mod[j, 10], 0], Directive[Gray, Thick, Opacity[0.5]],
     If[Equal[Mod[j, 5], 0], Directive[Gray, Opacity[0.5]],
      Directive[LightGray, Opacity[0.5]]
      ]
     ]
    },
   {j, 0, 10 Length[i]}
   ]
  ]
```

and getting the aspect ratio which yields a square raster

```
getAspect[{{minX_, maxX_}, {minY_, maxY_}}] :=
 Module[{stepx, stepy, i, rx, ry},
   i = (Ticks /.AbsoluteOptions[ListPlot[{{minX, minY}, {maxX, maxY}}], Ticks]);
   rx = Cases[i[[1]], {a_, ___, {_, AbsoluteThickness[0.25`]}} :> a];
   stepx = rx[[2]] - rx[[1]];
   ry = Cases[i[[2]], {a_, ___, {_, AbsoluteThickness[0.25`]}} :> a];
   stepy = ry[[2]] - ry[[1]];
  ((maxY - minY)/stepy)/((maxX - minX)/stepx)
  ]
```

---

**Test**

```
ELP[x_, y_, ex_, ey_, name_] := 
 ErrorListPlot[Cmb[x, y, ex, ey], PlotLabel -> name, Joined -> True, 
  Frame -> True, GridLines -> getGrid, ImageSize -> {600}, 
  PlotRangePadding -> 0, AspectRatio -> getAspect[FromTo[x, y]], 
  PlotRange -> FromTo[x, y]]


ELP[{4124961/25000000, 27573001/100000000, 9162729/25000000, 
  44635761/100000000, 15737089/25000000, 829921/1562500, 
  4405801/4000000, 23068809/25000000, 329386201/100000000, 
  58079641/100000000}, {1/10, 1/5, 3/10, 2/5, 3/5, 1/2, 1/2, 1/2, 1/2,
   1/2}, {2031/(250000 Sqrt[10]), 5251/(500000 Sqrt[10]), 
  3027/(250000 Sqrt[10]), 1/100000 6681/(500000 Sqrt[10]), 
  3967/(250000 Sqrt[10]), 911/(62500 Sqrt[10]), 
  2099/(100000 Sqrt[10]), 4803/(250000 Sqrt[10]), 
  18149/(500000 Sqrt[10]), 7621/(500000 Sqrt[10])}, {1/2000, 1/1000, 
  3/2000, 1/500, 3/1000, 1/400, 1/400, 1/400, 1/400, 1/400}, "T2, m"]
```

[image]

Here I divide the y-values by 20 and multiplied the x-values by 10000 to show the grid is still good:

[image]

---

**Final update (I hope)**

This uses FindDivisions as [suggested by belisarius](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664937/adaptive-gridlines/5670826#5670826). However, I used the three level line structure standard for milimeter paper as requested by Margus:

```
getGrid[x_, y_] := 
 FindDivisions[{x, y}, {10, 2, 5}] /. {r_, s_, t_} :> 
   Join[
     {#, Directive[Gray, Thick, Opacity[0.5]]} & /@ r, 
     {#, Directive[Gray, Opacity[0.5]]} & /@ Union[Flatten[s]], 
     {#, Directive[LightGray, Opacity[0.5]]} & /@ Union[Flatten[t]]
   ]
```

and

```
getAspect[{{minX_, maxX_}, {minY_, maxY_}}] :=
 Module[{stepx, stepy},
  stepx = (#[[2]] - #[[1]]) &@FindDivisions[{minX, maxX}, 10];
  stepy = (#[[2]] - #[[1]]) &@FindDivisions[{minY, maxY}, 10];
 ((maxY - minY)/stepy)/((maxX - minX)/stepx)
  ]
```

---

**WARNING!!!**

I just noticed that if you have this in MMA:

[image]

and you copy it to SO (just ctrl-c  ctrl-v), you get this:

```
(maxY - minY)/stepy/(maxX - minX)/stepx
```

which is **not mathematically equivalent**. It should be this:

```
((maxY - minY)*stepx)/((maxX - minX)*stepy)
```

I corrected this in the code above, but it has been posted wrong for half a day while working correctly on my computer. Thought that it would be good to mention this.

Comment: @Sjoerd C. de Vries : I tried approach like that, but using `Ceiling` and `Floor` function backfired, because on some variables the average change is around 10^4 and others 10^-4.

Comment: @Sjoerd C. de Vries : If i set `AspectRatio -> (Max[y] - Min[y])/(Max[x] - Min[x])`, and variable sizes are in same order of 10, then I think it even works (at least cases I tested). But that is not exactly what I am trying to do.

Comment: @Margus WRT your first comment: check my update; it should be good for all kinds of data ranges. WRT to comment #2: that doesn't work. What if y is huge and x small?

Comment: @Margus changed my update to include an automatic AspectRatio using your FromTo range input.

Comment: @Sjoerd someone needs to post this warning as a question.  If you don't, I will.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard OK, I'll try to come  up with a reasonable sounding question.

Comment: "What causes this, can it be fixed on our side, and if not, what is the best work-around?" seems valid to me.

Answer (score 4):

I think **FindDivisions[ ]** is what you're after:

> FindDivisions[{xmin,xmax},n] 
>       finds a list of about n "nice" numbers that divide the interval around xmin to xmax into equally spaced parts.

```
getTicks[x_, y_] := Flatten@FindDivisions[#, {10}] & /@ FromTo[x, y]
getGrid  [x_,y_] := FindDivisions[{x,y},{10,5}]/.
                          {r__,{s__}}:>Join@@{s,{#,{Gray,Thick}}&/@r}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Are we assured that FindDivisions[] yields the same ticks as Ticks->Automatic does? I couldn't find this in the  documentation. If it's not, this is not a guaranteed solution. But I guess FindDivisions[] exposes the routines mma itself uses. Nice, didn't know this one. This is one of the reasons I think the mma splash screen should have a random **Function Of The Day**, to increase the number of serendipitous finds like these. Since your mm paper still isn't precisely what Margus asked (three subdivisions are required with a square grid) I'll give an update using your code in my answer.

Comment: @Sjoerd "Assured" is a strong word. I tried several max-min sets, and it _seems_ to perform as _Ticks->Automatic_ does. That is clearly the intention in providing this function. WRT the **Function of the Day**, I'd rather prefer a serious doc reorganization, as a lot of features are almost unreachable by navigating the help.

Comment: @belisarius I'd expect a provision for logarithmic ticks to be used in logplots, but it seems FindDivisions[] doesn't have that. As to the 2nd remark: I agree that the help  could be better, but I usually find my way around it. As long as I know there is a function to do my task I can usually find it. Problem is knowing that such function exists. Perhaps you should assume that every function you'd want exists...

Comment: @Sjoerd I (humbly) think that the doc problem is far greater than "I can find my way". I keep finding things like this http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/TetGenLink/guide/TetGenLink.html that are buried somewhere behind obscure links, and could save me months of work.

Comment: @belisarius Indeed, this is amazing. Never knew we had this under the hood. I wonder what's more is in there.

Comment: @belisarius ...How did you find it? Another thing: What do you do when a new version of mma arrives? It's my feeling lots of old functions get new functionalities, but it may take years before you stumble upon them. The very useful capability of Do to iterate over lists in its argument that arrive in 6 if I'm not mistaken, is an example. I just chanced upon it but I would normally not look up an age old function like Do.

Comment: @Sjoerd Re:_How did you find it?_ That's the point. I can't remember. I just got there. The fun thing is, when I tried to find it again for answering your comment, as didn't remember the function names, it took me more than ten minutes to get there again. Finally I googled for it. **That is the point***

Comment: @Sjoerd @belisarius -- I stumbled across TetGenLink too and had a similar feeling of 'what else is buried in here?'... For what it's worth, I tend to find goodies in the documentation when searching for general terms and trolling through several pages of search results---rather than the typical 'search and pick from the first page' routine.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the same function for `FrameTicks` and `Gridlines`, they'll line up.

See [FrameTicks](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FrameTicks.html), and [GridLines](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GridLines.html?q=GridLines&lang=en). I think you'll need `ImageMargins` for the border.

Comment: -1 He already got Frame->true. He was also using GridLines. And FrameMargins is not an option of Plot

Comment: @Sjoerd I read his answer too quickly, it seems. But my point is really that he needed to coordinate FrameTicks with GridLines. I don't see any reference to FrameTicks.

Comment: OK, I removed the -1. Are you sure about ImageMargins? I have a hunch that it might be PlotRangePadding.

Comment: @Sjoerd Just before receiving your (justified) criticism about FrameMargins, I tried out both FrameMargins and ImageMargins, finding that the former does not work but the latter does. So I revised my original advice, recommending, instead, ImageMargins.

Comment: I can not use `FrameTicks -> GetGrid`, but it would be interesting to see, if that works for some cases.