# Force scientific notation in tick labels of ListLogLogPlot

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to custom-format tick labels on a ListLogLogPlot.  By searching Mathgroup archives, it looks like the usual way to mess with tick labels is to extract them using `AbsoluteOptions`, run a replacement rule with the custom format, and then explicitly feed them to the plotting function with the `Ticks->{...}` option.  However, the following doesn't work for ListLogLogPlot:

```
foo = ListLogLogPlot[Range[20]^3, Frame -> True];
ticks=(FrameTicks /. AbsoluteOptions[foo, FrameTicks])
```

Any ideas on how to deal with this?..

---

Edit: lots of good answers here!  Accepting Mr. Wizard's since it proved to be the most concise way to solve the immediate problem at hand, but I see myself using the other methods suggested in the future.

Comment: Yeah, i did it here: http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2009/Apr/msg00757.html and here: http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2009/Apr/msg00762.html, and by sheer accidence a couple of hours ago in this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664937/adaptive-gridlines/5666435#5666435

Comment: @Sjoerd why is this not an answer, so I can vote for it?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Well, as I see it, it's not actually an answer to Leo's question, which was about the error in ListLogLogPlot specifically. BTW: I just updated my answer referenced above to include new input by belisarius. The new code is less of a hack, but not suited for LogPlots as far as I can see. You still have to use the old method for that.  Another thing: I'd like to draw your attention to the rather unrelated warning below my final update. Not sure how to do it but I feel this warning should be known more widely.

Comment: @Sjoerd I took "Any ideas on how to deal with this?" to open the question up to alternative solutions.  I'll have to see if I can do something about your warning, it looks ugly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One can use replacements to mess with the labels directly, bypassing `Option`/`AbsoluteOptions`:

```
ListLogLogPlot[Range[20]^3, Frame -> True] /.
   (FrameTicks -> x_) :>
      (FrameTicks -> (x /. {a_?NumericQ, b_Integer, s___} :>
         {a, Superscript[10, Log10@b], s} ))
```

[image]

---

Thanks to [Alexey Popkov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/590388/alexey-popkov) this is now improved and less fragile.

Comment: Very elegant! +1. But one should use this with care because this trick relies on version-dependent behavior of `ListLogLogPlot`.

Comment: I think this code can be made much more general and less version-dependent just by replacing `{a_?NumericQ, b_Integer}` by `{a_?NumericQ, b_Integer, s___}` and `{a, Superscript[10, Log10@b]}` by `{a, Superscript[10, Log10@b], s}`.

Comment: @Alexey, please edit my answer with that, so your name appears on the answer too.  Try to keep the formatting, please.

Comment: I have made the edit but I have no enough privileges and the edit have to be reviewed. I do not know who should review it when it will be made.

Comment: @Alexey, I understand.  Do not try to make a second edit as that appears to cause both to be rejected.  If you refresh this page and you see the "This edit is only visible to you" banner is no longer there, someone rejected your edit.  If that happens, let me know, and I will make the edit myself, but I prefer that you get credit for your own edit!

Comment: Now the banner "This edit is only visible to you" no longer there. I am surprised!

Comment: @Alexey unfortunately the edit-reviewer didn't know what we wanted.  I will make the edit myself.  The only solution is for me to vote up your questions so you reach 2000 rep soon. :-)

Comment: @Wizard: upvoting answers gets him there faster :)

Comment: @yoda, true, but he is more an asker than an answerer, and that's not a bad thing, they are difficult questions!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I believe you could have approved the edit by selecting the edit link. I've only encountered it once, so I don't remember when it occurred. And, since you have a higher rep than me, you should have the same privileges. (btw, love the name.)

Comment: @rcollyer I'll look for that in the future.  (thanks. Don Herbert was great.)

Answer (score 5):

Like Sjoerd, I generally prefer to write a function that computes the ticks on the fly:

```
PowerTicks[label_][min_, max_] := Block[{min10, max10},
  min10 = Floor[Log10[min]];
  max10 = Ceiling[Log10[max]];
  Join[Table[{10^i, 
     If[label, Superscript[10, i], Spacer[{0, 0}]]}, {i, min10, 
     max10}],
   Flatten[
    Table[{k 10^i, 
      Spacer[{0, 0}], {0.005, 0.`}, {Thickness[0.001`]}}, {i, min10, 
      max10}, {k, 9}], 1]]
  ]

ListLogLogPlot[Range[20]^3, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{PowerTicks[True], 
    PowerTicks[False]}, {PowerTicks[True], PowerTicks[False]}}]
```

Answer (score 5):

To complement Brett's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669073/force-scientific-notation-in-tick-labels-of-listloglogplot/5671569#5671569), look at the `CustomTicks` package in [LevelScheme](http://wnsl.physics.yale.edu/levelscheme/). It provides two functions for generating tick marks 'LinTicks`and`LogTicks`, and each has a host of formatting options. Currently, it requires you to perform the logarithm yourself, i.e.

```
Plot[ {Log[10,Cosh[x]], Log[10, Sinh[x]]}, {x, 0, 4}, Frame -> True,
      FrameTicks -> { LinTicks, LogTicks, None, None }]
```

gives

[image: LogPlot of cosh and sinh over 0 to 4]

For a list of data, obviously you'd have to use `Log[Base, data]` with `ListPlot`, but it is workable.  I have submitted a patch to Mark Caprio so that the following would do the exact same thing as above

```
LogPlot[ {Cosh[x], Sinh[x]}, {x, 0, 4}, Frame -> True,
      FrameTicks -> { LinTicks, LogTicks, None, None }]
```

If the patch is accepted the old form of `LogTicks` would be accessible by setting the option `PlotType` to `Linear`, `Logarithmic` is default.  The advantage of using `CustomTicks` is that other bases are easy

[image: code for and plot of Exp[-x^2] from 0 to 3]

and it automatically formats it like you want.

**Edit**: I'd also like to point out, that `CustomTicks` is loadable by itself, separate from the rest of `LevelScheme`.  And, as it is a small package, there isn't all that much additional overhead.

Comment: @Simon, at the moment, the only issue is you have to perform the logarithms yourself. But, with luck, it won't be like that for long.

Comment: I resisted learning `LevelScheme` for years. Today's good experience with `CustomTicks` might finally change that. Thanks.

Comment: @ArgentoSapiens, `LevelScheme` takes getting used to, but `CustomTicks` is an awesome utility.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like a bug to me.  Simple calling `AbsoluteOptions[foo]` yields error messages.  Plain old `Options[foo]` works fine, though.

Answer (score 0):

Send an email with this code in it to support@Wolfram.com. They will be able to tell you if there's a known better workaround.