# FindDivisions[ ] not working as stated

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

[**FindDivisions[ ]**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FindDivisions.html) was added in Mma v7, and seems a nice way to get flexible ticks for plots. See for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664937/adaptive-gridlines) and its answers.

Usage example:

```
f[fd_] := Join[
   {#, #, {.07, 0}, Directive[Black, Thickness[.01]]} & /@ fd[[1]],
   {#, #, {.05, 0}, Directive[Black, Thin]}           & /@ Flatten[fd[[2]]]];
plot[pr_List] :=  
     Plot[Sin[x], Evaluate@Join[{x}, pr], Ticks -> {f[FindDivisions[pr, {2,5}]]}]

plot[{0, 10}]
```

[image]

And everything seems right.
But there is a glitch:

```
f[fd_] := Join[
   {#, #, {.03, 0}, Directive[Red, Thickness[.01]]} & /@  fd[[1]], 
   {#, #, {.05, 0}, Directive[Black, Thin]}         & /@  Flatten[fd[[2]]]];
plot[pr_List] :=
  Plot[Sin[x], Evaluate@Join[{x}, pr], Ticks -> {f[FindDivisions[pr, {2,5}]]}]
plot[{0, 10}]
```

[image]

As you can see, the red and black ticks are superimposed. That is because

```
FindDivisions[{0, 2}, {2, 4}]
(*
-> {{0, 1, 2}, {{0, 1/4, 1/2, 3/4, 1}, {1, 5/4, 3/2, 7/4, 2}}}
*)
```

and you can see that the numbers in the first list (the main ticks) are repeated in the second list.
However, the FindDivisions[] documentation states:

[image]

So, two questions:

1. Is this a bug, or am I doing (or understanding) something wrong?
2. Any *easy* way to delete the repeated ticks in a multilevel structure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a bug, probably in implementation, although having the duplicated values might be useful at times.  (It is certainly useful for constructing the different levels of divisions.)

For ticks, I'd probably use code like:

```
{major, minor} = FindDivisions[{0, 2}, {2, 4}];
minor = Complement[Flatten[minor], major];
```

to flatten the hierarchy and remove duplicates.

---

Generalized, for more levels than just two:

```
divs = Flatten /@ FindDivisions[{0, 2}, {2, 4, 2}];
Complement[#2, #1] & @@@ Partition[divs, 2, 1, -1, {{}}]
```

Comment: Thanks @Brett. How does it work for `FindDivisions[{0, 2}, {2, 4, 2}]`?

Comment: Answer updated, although I don't care for the divisions it found for the third level in this case...

Comment: Seems that with `FindDivisions[{0, 1}, {3, 3, 3}]`, the value `1/2` gets repeated in the third list

Comment: Yes, because the second level divisions share an interval (2/5,3/5) from straddling the 1/2 in the first division.  This is a result of the "The first and last numbers may be slightly outside the range x_min to x_max" note in the documentation.

Comment: @Brett Yep. My second question is _"Any easy way to delete the repeated ticks in a multilevel structure?"_ :)

Comment: You could try `FindDivisions[{0, 1}, {3, 3, 3}, Method -> "Legacy"]` although it might introduce undesirable gaps in the ticks.